# "cut the bite" - is this a common expression?

Tags: expressions

Is *to cut the bite* a common expression to express making something milder? As in *putting lemon in the recipe cuts the bite of the garlic*?

I thought it made sense but no one seems to understand what I'm trying to say!

Comment: https://www.google.pt/search?q=how+to+cut+the+bite+of+garlic&oq=cut+the+bite&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0j69i60j0l3.9417j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Between lemons and garlic, it would be more common to use *bite* with the lemon. This might have set up the cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 2):

**cuts the bite** can be interpreted as **to reduce the strong flavor of garlic in the dish**, with **cut** meaning **reduce**, and **bite** equivalent to **strong flavor**.

EDIT: As for the usage of the expression itself: it's indeed strange, but not something too exotic or esoteric. In fact, I'd say the phrase is quite useful when it comes to describing the process of **making something milder** in a shorter and more concise manner, while also retaining the original meaning.

Comment: I think the OP knows what it means, and is asking whether it’s a common expression.

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted what OP was trying to say. Thank you for the feedback. An edit has been made to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

To cut the bite of a pungent ingredient, like onions or garlic is the correct term.

Cut = 2a : trim, pare, e.g., cut one's nails [according to merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut) and bite = 7b : a sharp penetrating effect e.g.,The soup has a peppery bite. [according to merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bite)

A simple google search of [to cut the bite of garlic](https://www.google.pt/search?ei=K3BoW5ziKcrawQLE3KJQ&q=to%20cut%20the%20bite%20of%20garlic&oq=to%20cut%20the%20bite%20of%20garlic&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1.2317.2317.0.2614.1.1.0.0.0.0.100.100.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.100....0.UE79xFzQv4c) yielded 50 000 000 results.

Alternatively, you could say [tame the flavour](https://www.seriouseats.com/2017/02/make-the-most-out-of-garlic-chopping-acid-heat.html) or even [neutralize the flavour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17321/how-do-i-neutralize-a-strong-garlic-flavor).

Note that there is a [cooking stackexchange site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) where you can learn about more cooking terms.

Comment: Most of the hits in that Google search do not contain the phrase in question.